# How to persist the MUI Transfer List data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, material-ui

I am using the Transfer List as a reusable component that receives two arrays, that are filled with api data.

Today, the lists are filled like this.:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setLeft(
      JSON.parse(
        JSON.stringify(
          leftList.map((value: any) => ({ name: value.name, id: value.id }))
        )
      )
    );
  }, [JSON.stringify(leftList)]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setRight(
      JSON.parse(
        JSON.stringify(
          rightList.map((value: any) => ({ name: value.name, id: value.id }))
        )
      )
    );
  }, [JSON.stringify(rightList)]);
```

I can transfer data and submit to an endpoint. However, when I reload the page after the data submit, the data remains the same as before the update.

I used JSON.stringify as a try to persist the data but I guess that it's not the best solution.

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem you're facing.